# How do I specify a quartz property file outside of the classpath in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, quartz

I'm attempting to specify my quartz properties file in gradle. From a 'config' directory rather than from resources.

```
String quartzProperties = System.properties['org.quartz.properties'] ?: "file:config/local/quartz.properties"
System.setProperty("org.quartz.properties", quartzProperties)
```

The output from

```
(System.properties).each {
    println "Prop ${it}"
}
```

or the properties task, is

```
Prop quartz.properties=file:config/local/quartz.properties
```

The output from quartz is

```
PropertiesFactoryBean      --- Loading properties file from class path resource [quartz.properties]
SchedulerConfig$$EnhancerB --- Cannot load quartz.properties.
```

The symptom of it not being set is that I am getting the wrong sql dialect so the application gives a database error on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question and looking at your code, using `file:config/local/quartz.properties` was wrong most likely. The official docs really only put a path into that property, without any URI-prefix or whatsoever. That prefix most likely made the path invalid and Quartz was unable to find it. The following is an [example from GitHub](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/distribution/src/main/assembly/root/examples/example10/example10.sh):

```
workdir=`dirname $0`
workdir=`cd ${workdir} && pwd`
QUARTZ=${workdir}/../..
[...]
# Set the name and location of the quartz.properties file
QUARTZ_PROPS="-Dorg.quartz.properties=${workdir}/quartz.properties"
```

At least one available [factory](https://github.com/Flipkart/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.java#L367) really only uses a file as well:

```
    String requestedFile = System.getProperty(PROPERTIES_FILE);
    String propFileName = requestedFile != null ? requestedFile
            : "quartz.properties";
    File propFile = new File(propFileName);
```

Besides that, at least nowadays [some factories](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html#StdSchedulerFactory-java.util.Properties-) exist which support providing settings directly:

```
StdSchedulerFactory(Properties props)
Create a StdSchedulerFactory that has been initialized via initialize(Properties).

initialize(InputStream propertiesStream)
Initialize the SchedulerFactory with the contents of the Properties file opened with the given InputStream.
```